# Get current compilation unit name within #include

Tags: c++, c, macros

My current goal is to create one (or as few as possible) line of code that will switch the remainder of the active compilation unit to an unoptimized, debug configuration.  My first instincts were either:

```
FORCE_DEBUG;
// code below here will be forced to be unoptimized and in a debug environment
```

or

```
#include "ForceDebug.h"
// code below here will be forced to be unoptimized and in a debug environment
```

would be ideal.  In my workspace, to convert to an unoptimized debug configuration requires I change the pragma optimize level, but also #undef some macros and #define other macros.

The FORCE_DEBUG macro doesn't work because it would need to execute preprocessor directives #undef and #define which I understand are not evaluatable within a macro.

Instead I have a working version of #include "ForceDebug.h".   But I want to message the developer that they have disabled optimization on a given compilation unit (so they don't check it in, or if they do check it in that it can be caught and fixed).  Ideally this message includes the filename of whichever file #includes "ForceDebug.h" or the current compilation unit.

Here's an approx ForceDebug.h

```
#pragma once

#pragma message("DISABLING OPTIMIZATION IN" COMPILATION_UNIT_FILE)

#undef _RELEASE
#define _DEBUG

#ifdef _MSC_VER
# pragma optimize("", off)
#else
# pragma GCC optimize("O0")
#endif
```

So a call site would look something like Foo.cpp:

```
// this messages "ForceDebug.h", I want to message "Foo.cpp"
//#define COMPILATION_UNIT_FILE __FILE__ 

// double macro also messages "ForceDebug.h"
//#define COMPILATION_UNIT_FILE COMPILATION_UNIT_FILE2(__FILE__)
//#define COMPILATION_UNIT_FILE2(x) x

// this works but requires doing it manually, which I'm trying to avoid
#define COMPILATION_UNIT_FILE "Foo.cpp"
#include "ForceDebug.h"
// code below here will be forced to be unoptimized, debug environment
```

I can't use `__FILE__` because that messages about ForceDebug.h, when I want it to report about Foo.cpp.

If I could evaluate `__FILE__` inside Foo.cpp and pass the evaluated version into ForceDebug.h that would be acceptable, but I tried recursive macro calls and it still reported ForceDebug.h

Is there any way to get it to pass "Foo.cpp" into the include or to derive that value by some other means for either clang or Visual Studio?

Comment: The current file's name is in `__FILE__`.

Comment: Oops, I know about `__FILE__` but it doesn't transfer from Foo.cpp to ForceDebug.h correctly, it reports "ForceDebug.h" and not "Foo.cpp"

Comment: I've modified the question to reflect that I know about `__FILE__` but that doesn't get me to report Foo.cpp

Comment: `#define COMPILATION_UNIT_FILE __FILE__` in `foo.cpp` [or whatever] should do the trick. But no, there is no way to do this within the header.

Comment: @MatsPetersson So then usage of that macro inside a header gives the headers name… as the asker described.

Comment: `#define COMPILATION_UNIT_FILE __FILE__` in Foo.cpp defines the macro there, but its evaluating the macro in ForceDebug.h and thus reports ForceDebug.h when it evaluates COMPILATION_UNIT_FILE, not Foo.cpp

Comment: Ah, of course, you need a "double level macro" so that the macro expands the from the first to the second. So `#define COMPILATION_UNIT_FILE XCOMPILATION_UNIT(__FILE__)` and `#define XCOMPILATION_UNIT(x) x`

Comment: I also tried that before posting, it also reports ForceDebug.h

Comment: If you use `#pragma warning` instead of `#pragma message`, you should get a line before the warning saying `In file included from filename.c:line`. Does that help at all?

Comment: @RogerHanna: Possibly `__BASE_FILE__` might meet the purpose for CLANG(but I don't know similar alternative for VC).

Comment: @IseWisteria that might do it, I'll give it a shot...  one platform is better than none :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to emit the current compilation unit name from an included file.

However, your proposed syntax requires the user of `"ForceDebug.h"` to add another directive to expose its compilation unit name to the header file. Instead, you can turn it around and allow simple inclusion that defines a macro that allows for the message to be emitted.

While, generally speaking, macros cannot be used to generate pre-processor directives, there is a syntax for pragmas for the compilers you illustrated. MSVC and GCC each have their own syntax, but conditional compilation can make the syntax appear uniform.

In your source file:

```
#include "ForceDebug.h"
FORCE_DEBUG;

//... rest of source
```

In `"ForceDebug.h"`:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define DO_PRAGMA(X) __pragma(X)
#define NO_OPT optimize("", off)
#else
#define DO_PRAGMA2(X) _Pragma(#X)
#define DO_PRAGMA(X) DO_PRAGMA2(X)
#define NO_OPT GCC optimize("O0")
#endif

#define FORCE_DEBUG \
        DO_PRAGMA(message("DISABLING OPTIMIZATION IN " __FILE__)) \
        DO_PRAGMA(NO_OPT) \
        struct __force_debug

#undef _RELEASE
#define _DEBUG
```

Comment: it hurts noting to place such a __FILE__ reference in the source file, even if the resulting string is never used.   Then the header file can have a macro that enables the block/line of code that contains the __FILE__ reference

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `__FILE__` [predefined macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) like below:

```
#pragma message("DISABLING OPTIMIZATION IN " __FILE__)
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bdb918bbb46a1f6)

Edit:

Since you want to report about the .cpp file I would go the other way around. That is, I would change ForceDebug.h to:

```
#pragma once

#undef _RELEASE
#define _DEBUG
#define OPT_OFF
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

#ifdef _MSC_VER
# pragma optimize("", off)
#else
# pragma GCC optimize("O0")
#endif
```

And then I would put the potensial message in my .cpp file:

```
#include "foo.h"

...

#ifdef OPT_OFF
#pragma message("DISABLING OPTIMIZATION IN " __FILE__)
#endif
```

Comment: Oops, I know about `__FILE__` but it doesn't transfer from Foo.cpp to ForceDebug.h correctly, it reports "ForceDebug.h" and not "Foo.cpp"

Comment: I've modified the question to reflect that I know about `__FILE__` but that doesn't get me to report Foo.cpp

Comment: The reverse direction is an interesting solution but also error prone since it assumes someone would put the 2nd line in.

`#include "ForceDebug.h" \ MESSAGE_DEBUG;`

Comment: And unfortunately if the OPT_OFF messaging isn't included in the compilation unit, the user's error results in concealed ForceDebug.h inclusions, which is what the messaging is intended to avoid.

Comment: the premise of this question seems to be in doubt.   The source code will always have the #include "ForceDebug.h" statement, so the source file will always be not optimized.   Suggest use a much better technique of re-compiling that file with `-O0`. (no optimization)  then link.   and when you want an optimized version, then compile the same as  all the other source files.   This special handling of a file can be easily implemented in a `makefile` that can handle `-D` parameters for the specific file name to not optimize.